# How to put a certain character before a certain string?

Tags: java, string

What I am trying to do is put the @ character before the domain. Im also trying to figure out how to put the domains to be the last 4 characters (example .com). How do I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

I have listed my work on this [link](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=c2Nx1BFe).

Code from the link:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Must be between 8 and 20 characters.");
                System.out.println("Must contain at least one uppercase and lowercase letter.");
                System.out.println("Must contain at least one digit. ");
                System.out.println("Must contain a special character ] [ ? / < ~ # ! $ % ^ & * ( ) + = } | :  ; , > { ");
                System.out.println("Must contain @ before the domain");
                System.out.println("The only acceptable domains are .com .edu .org .mil .gov .net");
                System.out.println("\\n____Please enter your username to access the page. Follow the rules above.____ ");

                String input = keyboard.nextLine();
                while ((input.length() < 8) || (input.length() > 20))
                {
                System.out.println("Error! Your input is not valid.");
                System.out.println("Please try again.");
                keyboard.nextLine();
                }

                        for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++)
                    {
                        if(Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i)))
                        {
                                break;                         
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                if(i == input.length())
                                {
                                        System.out.println("Error: Try again");
                                        input = keyboard.nextLine();
                                }
                        }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++)
                    {
                        if(Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(i)))
                        {
                                break;                         
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                if(i == input.length())
                                {
                                        System.out.println("Try again");
                                        input = keyboard.nextLine();
                                }
                        }
                        }

                         char [] numbers=  {\'0\',\'1\',\'2\',\'3\', \'4\',\'5\',\'6\',\'7\',\'8\',\'9\'};
                         char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

                         for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
                         {
                                 for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
                                 {
                                         if (inputArray[i]== numbers[j])
                                 {  
                                                 i=inputArray.length;
                         j=numbers.length;

                                 }
                                  else
                                 {
                                          if(i == inputArray.length-1 && j== numbers.length-1)
                                 {
                                                  System.out.println("Try again");       
                                                  input = keyboard.nextLine();


                                 }
                                 }
                                 }




char [] SpecialCharacter = {\']\',\'[\',\'?\',\'/\',\'<\',\'~\',\'#\',\'.\',\'!\',\'$\',\'%\',\'^\',\'&\',\'*\',\'(\',\')\',\'+\',\'=\',\'}\',\'|\',\'>\',\'{\' };
                         char[] inputArray2 = input.toCharArray();

                         for (int k = 0; k < inputArray2.length; k++)
                         {
                                 for (int l = 0; l < SpecialCharacter.length; l++)
                                 {
                                         if (inputArray2[k]== SpecialCharacter[l])
                                 {  
                                                 k=inputArray2.length;
                         l=SpecialCharacter.length;    
                                 }
                                  else
                                 {
                                          if(k == inputArray2.length-1 && l == SpecialCharacter.length-1)
                                 {
                                      System.out.println("No...Try Again");
                                      input = keyboard.nextLine();
                                 }
                                 }
                                 }

                                 String domain1 = ".com";
                                 String domain2 = ".edu";
                                 String domain3 = ".org";
                                 String domain4 = ".mil";
                                 String domain5 = ".gov";
                                 String domain6 = ".net";


                         }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add code into the question directly rather than just linking to pastebin - but *format it sensibly first*. Additionally, that pastebin is over 130 lines long - I would expect you to be able to demonstrate the problem easily within 20 lines, which would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: DEAR LORD, what is this code!? Firslty, you do know that you're burning all te bridges you've made so far when you enter the new value... My recomendation would be to make a boolean marker `isGood` then make a while loop in which you first read the keyboard and then check each of the prerequisites, and as soon as one doesn't fit, you make the `isGood` marker false and use `continue`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only need to verify that the user has entered a valid email or not then you should use regular expersion for that it makes it more easy and fast.

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class EmailValidator {

private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
    "^(?=.*[0-9]*[a-z]*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}+@[A-Za-z0-9]+.(com|org|edu|mil|net))$";

public EmailValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
}

/**
 * Validate hex with regular expression
 * 
 * @param hex
 *            hex for validation
 * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
 */
public boolean validate(final String hex) {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
    return matcher.matches();

}
   }
```

hope this will help you. =)

Comment: i'm not sure this regex checks if the length is between 8 and 20, if the email contains a special character or at least one digit...

Comment: for that you can just do this **String checking[]=emailString.split("@");  --  if(checking[0].length()<8||checking[0].length()>20)System.out.print("Invalid");else// your code**

Comment: you just have to add these two lines in the code above and you are done =) and do it if it matches the pattern else skip it. Accept this regex can do all you want.

Comment: yes, but your regex still doesn't check if he used all: uppercase, lowercase, digit and special character...

Comment: **(?=.*[0-9]*[a-z]*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}+@[A-Za-z0-9]+.(com|org|edu|mil|net))**

here you go dear.. its running,, verified on http://www.myregextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

i'll just put this here...

Insert the parts of your code where needed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Username {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Must be between 8 and 20 characters.");
            System.out.println("Must contain at least one uppercase and lowercase letter.");
            System.out.println("Must contain at least one digit. ");
            System.out.println("Must contain a special character ] [ ? / < ~ # ! $ % ^ & * ( ) + = } | :  ; , > { ");
            System.out.println("Must contain @ before the domain");
            System.out.println("The only acceptable domains are .com .edu .org .mil .gov .net");
            System.out.println("\\n____Please enter your username to access the page. Follow the rules above.____ ");

            boolean isOK = false;
            String input=new String();

            while(!isOK){
                input=keyboard.nextLine();

                if(input.length() < 20 || input.length() > 8) //length check
                {
                    isOK=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isOK=false;
                    continue;
                }

                if(input.contains('@')) //check domain
                {
                    isOK=true;                      
                }
                else
                {
                    isOK=false;
                    System.out.println("No @ before domain!");
                    continue;
                }

                String[] tokens = input.split("@");
                String domain=tokens[1];
                String username=tokens[0];

                //check if contains digit
                ...

                //check uppercase and lowercase in username
                ...
                //check special character in username
                ...

                //split domain
                tokens = domain.split(".");
                String domainEnding = tokens[1];

                //check if the input domain endings are allowed
                ...


            }
    }
}
```

So where the part of input is wrong just use `isOK=false;
                        continue;`

BTW: why are you using `\'` in special character and number arrays?
You could use just `'1'` , `'@'` etc.